# Get Django Request from SRCP method Spyne?

Tags: python, django, spyne

I have a SRCP and accurate method that only authenticate the user before performing the task. I was able to login using Basic Authentication in Django, but could not recover the request of the data, the user for example, within the SRCP method.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to retrieve the request using the answer the question below:

[Django: How can i get the logged user outside of view request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107695/django-how-can-i-get-the-logged-user-outside-of-view-request)